# How to list Files and Folders using Google Cloud Client Library for Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to list files and folders using the Google Cloud Client Library for Java?

```
try (CloudStorageFileSystem fs = CloudStorageFileSystem.forBucket("demo")){       
     Path path = fs.getPath("/");
}
```

What I would need here is to list of the Folders and Subfolders (and Files) inside the 'demo' bucket.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the reference here from Google: [Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries)

```
import com.google.cloud.storage.Bucket;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;

public static void printGCSItems(){

    Set folders = new HashSet();
    Set files = new HashSet();

    // Instantiates a client
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    // Get the bucket
    Bucket bucket = storage.get("demo");

    Page<Blob> blobs = bucket.list();
    for (Blob blob : blobs.iterateAll()) {
       // Gets the path of the object
        String path = blob.getName();

        if (isDir(path) && !folders.contains(path)){ // If the object is a folder, then add it to folders set
            folders.add(path);
        } else { // If the object isn't a folder, then extract the parent path and add it to folders set
            String parentDir = getParentDir(path);
            if (!folders.contains(parentDir)){
                folders.add(parentDir);
                System.out.println(parentDir);
            }
            files.add(path);
        }
        System.out.println(path);
    }
}

public static boolean isDir(String path){
    return path.endsWith("/");
}

public static String getParentDir(String path){
    return path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
}
```